# What's the difference between NSTimer and performSelector:afterDelay:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, nstimer

I want to do something every x seconds y times. Is there a specific advantage to using either method, using NSTimer's scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: vs performSelector:afterDelay:?

Comment: `NSTimer` is a class, `performSelector:afterDelay:` is a selector.

Comment: I meant in terms of applying it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of difference.

`performSelector` only sends a message to the receiver with an object as the argument. (required)

But You can achieve more with  `NSTimer`

Few Examples,

> You can specify whether a timer is repeating or non-repeating at creation time.
>
> You can Schedule Timers in Run Loops

For more, please read the [NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer can repeat and is its own object that you can check against nil on. I'm sure there are other things too but those are what usually matter the most.